# TypeError: employee.includes is not a function

Tags: javascript, json

I got the following objects. I want to filter them in javascript, and get alle the objects with the area name of "Vibestuen".

```
[
        {
            "id": 292,
            "name": "Hans",
            "image": "as",
            "calculatedVacation": 1.0,
            "area": {
                "name": "Ikke tilknyttet en stue"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 295,
            "name": "xx",
            "image": "zz",
            "calculatedVacation": 2.0,
            "area": {
                "name": "Vibestuen"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 296,
            "name": "xx",
            "image": "abccc.png",
            "calculatedVacation": 2.0,
            "area": {
                "name": "Andestuen"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 298,
            "name": "bunun",
            "image": "zz",
            "calculatedVacation": 2.0,
            "area": null
        },
        {
            "id": 299,
            "name": "lort",
            "image": "kol",
            "calculatedVacation": 2.0,
            "area": {
                "name": "Vibestuen"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Currently my javascript looks as follows:

```
fetch(baseURL + "/employees")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(result => {
    let vibeEmployees = result.filter(employee => employee.includes('Vibestuen'));

    console.log(vibeEmployees)
})
```

Im getting the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: employee.includes is not a function
at showEmployeeVibe.js:4
at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
at showEmployeeVibe.js:4
```

How do i filter these objects?

Comment: `employee.area && employee.area.name == 'Vibestuen'`…?

Comment: [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining): `let vibeEmployees = result.filter(employee => employee.area?.name.includes('Vibestuen'));
`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

includes check if parameter is contained on Array. You filter should look like this

```
result.filter(employee => employee.area && employee.area.name === 'Vibestuen')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
let vibeEmployee = result.filter(employee => employee.area && employee.area.name === 'Vibestuen')
```

Answer (score -1):

Need to change the condition inside filter callback function. employee represents an object and area is null in few records.

Example:
`let vibeEmployees = data.filter( (employee) => employee.area && employee.area.name.includes("Vibestuen") );`